# using concat select firstname and lastname search

Tags: php, mysql

This is my sql query. I need to search first name and last name using search.

```
$result =  'SELECT * FROM resume 
            WHERE   (first_name LIKE "'.$sKeyword.'%" OR 
                     last_name LIKE "'.$sKeyword.'%" OR
                     CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) like "'.$sKeyword.'%" OR 
                     email LIKE "'.$sKeyword.'%" OR 
                     phone LIKE "'.$sKeyword.'%" OR 
                     zip_code LIKE "'.$sKeyword.'%" OR 
                     find_us LIKE "'.$sKeyword.'%" )';
```

Comment: so are you getting any error?

Comment: well, is there any errors or anything...because i think this will work just fine..

Comment: no i didnt got any error from this query it just find null result when i search with firstname and last name.this query doesn’t work properly.

Comment: @$sKeyword for every condition. To strange and fishy!

Comment: You have no leading % on your LIKEs, hence they will only find matches where the field starts with the keyword you are searching for. Adding a leading % will prevent MySQL using its indexes which will result in it performing very badly (and even if you fix this, the numerous OR clauses will also cause index issues)

Answer (score 2):

fetch result as simple query and display the result using concatination...

```
$seresult='SELECT * FROM resume 
            WHERE   (first_name LIKE "%'.$sKeyword.'%" OR 
                     last_name LIKE "%'.$sKeyword.'%" OR
                     email LIKE "%'.$sKeyword.'%" OR 
                     phone LIKE "%'.$sKeyword.'%" OR 
                     zip_code LIKE "%'.$sKeyword.'%" OR 
                     find_us LIKE "%'.$sKeyword.'%" )';
```

and after while displaying

```
<?= $seresult['first_name']; ?>-<?= $seresult['last_name']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you run the query just check that data is present in the table.

Try something like below:

```
$fullName = "john martin";
$nameArray = explode(" ",$fullName);
if(count($nameArray)>1)
  $search = " first_name in (".implode(',',$nameArray).") OR last_name in (".implode(',',$nameArray).")";
else
  $search = " first_name LIKE "%'.$sKeyword.'%" OR last_name LIKE "%'.$sKeyword.'%" OR"

$seresult='SELECT * FROM resume 
            WHERE   ('.$search.'
                     email LIKE "%'.$sKeyword.'%" OR 
                     phone LIKE "%'.$sKeyword.'%" OR 
                     zip_code LIKE "%'.$sKeyword.'%" OR 
                     find_us LIKE "%'.$sKeyword.'%" )';
```

**EDIT**: As per your comment updated the query

Comment: ok Thankyou suresh .hope this will work for me

Comment: so raheel can you tell me the right way for it..

Comment: actully when i put full name in search e.g (john martin) it doesnt give any result to me :(

Comment: @Honey: than your query and php code will be different. Explode it with space and than search in query with IN(). than it will work

Comment: @honey: updated my query just try it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      $seresult='SELECT * FROM resume 
            WHERE   (first_name LIKE "%'.$sKeyword.'%" OR 
                             first_name LIKE "'.$sKeyword.'%" OR 
                             first_name LIKE "%'.$sKeyword.'" OR 
                            last_name LIKE "%'.$sKeyword.'%" OR
                            last_name LIKE "'.$sKeyword.'%" OR
                            last_name LIKE "%'.$sKeyword.'" OR
                            email LIKE "%'.$sKeyword.'%" OR 
                            phone LIKE "%'.$sKeyword.'%" OR 
                            zip_code LIKE "%'.$sKeyword.'%" OR 
                            find_us LIKE "%'.$sKeyword.'%" )';
```

Answer (score 0):

Splitting off the ORs into different UNIONed queries should allow MySQL to use its indexes more efficiently.

I assume you are looking for items that only start with the entered phrase. If so this might help, as it will only do a combined search of first_name and last_name if there is a space in the search phrase.

```
$result =  "SELECT * FROM resume 
            WHERE   first_name LIKE '$sKeyword%' 
            UNION
            SELECT * FROM resume 
            WHERE   last_name LIKE '$sKeyword%' 
            UNION
            SELECT * FROM resume 
            WHERE   email LIKE '$sKeyword%'
            UNION
            SELECT * FROM resume 
            WHERE   phone LIKE '$sKeyword%'
            UNION
            SELECT * FROM resume 
            WHERE   zip_code LIKE '$sKeyword%'
            UNION
            SELECT * FROM resume 
            WHERE   find_us LIKE '$sKeyword%'
            UNION
            SELECT * FROM resume 
            WHERE   CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) like '$sKeyword%'";

$sKeywordArray = explode(' ', $sKeyword);
IF (count($sKeywordArray) > 1)
{
    $result2 = array();     
    foreach($sKeywordArray $value)
    {
        $result2[] = "(first_name like '$value%' OR last_name like '$value%')";
    }
    $result .= " UNION SELECT * FROM resume WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $result2)
}
```